# Cayley graph of the infinity dihedral group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know how to construct the Cayley graph for $D_n$, but I have no idea how one would draw a Cayley graph for $D_\infty = <r,s|s^2=e, (sr)^2=e>$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I like this Cayley graph for $D_\infty$. Maybe you can see how to modify it to give a Cayley graph for the presentation you gave?

My generators will be $s$ and $t = sr$. So $D_\infty = \langle s,t \mid s^2=t^2 = e\rangle$. The Cayley graph is the real line: place vertices at integer points, and place alternate labels on edges $s$ and $t$. Note that I use the convention of drawing only one edge when a generator has order two. Thus the vertices are labeled by strings alternating between $s$ and $t$, e.g. $stststs$.